# Do we need semicolon in mysql> source filename; to run batch file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows, batch-file

I have a sql batch file at location `D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql`. The batch file is as:

```
use menagerie;
select * from event
```

Note that there is no semicolon after the last line. Nor any linebreak(`\n`)

I want to run this file through `mysql` prompt. The [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html) says to put a semicolon in the end of query as:

```
mysql> source filename;
```

When I run the query I am lead to a bizarre situation as:

```
mysql> source D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql;
ERROR:
Unknown command '\S'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\m'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\i'.
    -> ;
    -> ;
    ->
```

As can be seen I can't get rid of `->`. And what are these errors?

On the other hand if I remove the semicolon from the query, everything works fine as:

```
mysql> source D:\Softwear\mysql\install\data\bat.sql
Database changed
+----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+
| name     | date       | type     | remark                       |
+----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+
| Tommy    | 2000-01-02 | litter   | 4 kittens, 3 females, 1 male |
| Bowser   | 2001-04-26 | vet      | needed break straightened    |
| puffball | 2002-05-13 | birthday | gave him a new chew toy      |
+----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Why am I getting the errors and the weird behavior of prompt when adding the semicolon? Did the doc mistakenly added the semicolon?

P.S: Even if I put any delimiter like `;` or `\n` at the end of `bat.sql` it doesn't make any difference. I still receive errors if I put `;` at the end of query.

Comment: Seems like docs have made a typo. On the [linked page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html). They don't use the smicolon: `mysql> source file_name
mysql> \. file_name`

Comment: Depending on the contents of the file, you might need to change the `DELIMITER`. You will need to share (at least part of) the file so we can be of any help.

Comment: @FDavidov I've added the `sql` file to the question. Changing the `DELIMITER` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I don't see the file.

Comment: @FDavidov The very first lines of the question The batch file is as:

use menagerie;
select * from event   PS: SO doesn't allow to upload files.

Comment: you completely lost me. Sorry.

Comment: @FDavidov No problem.